# class not found exception error occur while running code in java

Tags: java

i tried this code. [image]
after fill this as I shown in picture click transfer button the exception will be
throw java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
this my database tables

accountholder

acno | balance

TransferDetails
acno1 | acno2 | amount

please fix this error

```
import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.sql.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    class DatabaseBean
    {
    Connection con1=null;

        public DatabaseBean( ) throws Exception
        {
             Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
             con1=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:dsnjsp","sa","");
           }

         public Connection getConnection( )
        {
            return con1;
            }
       }

    public class MoneyTransfer extends JFrame
    {
        JLabel label1,label2, label3;
        JLabel heading;

        JTextField text1,text2,text3;
        JButton but1;

        public MoneyTransfer( ){

            label1=new JLabel("From A/c Number");
            label2=new JLabel("To A/c Number");
            label3=new JLabel("Amount ");
            text1=new JTextField(5);
            text2=new JTextField(5);
            text3=new JTextField(5);

            heading=new JLabel("Money Transfer - using transaction ");
            heading.setFont(new Font("Curlz MT",Font.BOLD,12));
            but1=new JButton("Transfer");
            ButtonHandler handler1=new ButtonHandler( );
            but1.addActionListener(handler1);

            JPanel panel1=(JPanel)getContentPane( );
            panel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout( ) );
            panel1.add(heading);
            panel1.add(label1);
            panel1.add(text1);
            panel1.add(label2);
            panel1.add(text2);
            panel1.add(label3);
            panel1.add(text3);
            panel1.add(but1);
            setSize(420,120);
            setVisible(true);
            setLocation(200,200);

        }


    class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            int _acno1= Integer.parseInt( text1.getText( ));
            int _acno2= Integer.parseInt( text2.getText( ));
            float _amount= Float.parseFloat( text3.getText( ));

            DatabaseBean db1=null;

            try{
            db1 = new DatabaseBean( );
            java.sql.Connection con1=db1.getConnection( );

            con1.setAutoCommit(false);

            PreparedStatement st1=con1.prepareStatement("update accountholder set balance=balance-? where acno=?");
            st1.setFloat(1,_amount);
            st1.setInt(2,_acno1);
            st1.executeUpdate( );

            PreparedStatement st2=con1.prepareStatement("update accountholder set balance=balance+? where acno=?");
            st2.setFloat(1,_amount);
            st2.setInt(2,_acno2);
            st2.executeUpdate( );

            PreparedStatement st3=con1.prepareStatement("insert into TransferDetails(acno1,acno2,amount) values(?,?,?)");
            st3.setInt(1,_acno1);
            st3.setInt(2,_acno2);
            st3.setFloat(3,_amount);
            st3.executeUpdate( );

            PreparedStatement st4=con1.prepareStatement("select balance from accountholder where acno=?");
            st4.setInt(1,_acno1);
            ResultSet rs1=st4.executeQuery( );
            rs1.next( );

            if(rs1.getFloat(1)< 0)
            {
                con1.rollback();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"transaction failed");
                }
            else
             {
                con1.commit( );
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"transaction executed successfully");
                }

           clearscreen( );
           }catch(Exception ee)
            {
                System.out.println( ee.toString());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"excception caught");

                }

        }

    void clearscreen( )
    {
        text1.setText("");
        text2.setText("");
        text3.setText("");
        text1.requestFocus( );
        }
    }
        public static void main(String[ ] args)
        {
            MoneyTransfer instance1= new MoneyTransfer ( );
            }
    }
```

Comment: Did you installed the driver ?

Comment: ya. I have install the required drivers

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Java 8`, which is most probably the case, the JDBC-ODBC bridge has been removed. Refer to this thread in order to change connection properties [Access Database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc/)

**MsSQL**
In order to connect to mssql simply use `sqlserver`driver

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=MYDB;integratedSecurity=true";
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

Comment: i have connected sql server 2000 database not access

Comment: @LoshiniLoganathan updated answer. Please, include in your question these small details, like which database are you using, so that everyone understands what you need. Since ODBC is used to connect mainly to MS Access

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver this exception was thrown

Comment: @LoshiniLoganathan, of course. You have to include sqljdbc4.jar into your lib and specify paths.

Comment: You can try to research a bit. It's simple if you put some efforts towards it.